# Cannot transfer ERC20 token, "Bad instruction" error

Tags: erc-20, contract-debugging, address.transfer, ruby

I'm trying to transfer an ERC20 token from account A to account B. Account A deployed the contract and owns all tokens.

Looks like I'm missing something very obvious.

Every time I try to transfer tokens from one account to another, I get a error. [Here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x70901f84dc3b97fa5e74a87aae1d2da4cdd07de6ba661e10027c33b2803eff8c) is an example of erroneous transaction.

Addresses in question:

- Account A: [`0xd8e05701eff33acfda0a8e24c04070347703c72c`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd8e05701eff33acfda0a8e24c04070347703c72c)
- Account B: [`0x3a70ceac36c8111a95b573d76ad75b7ba898662b`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x3a70ceac36c8111a95b573d76ad75b7ba898662b)
- Contract: [`0x1caf5380b7adc2e4e93c2828f895693ff38c3947`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x1caf5380b7adc2e4e93c2828f895693ff38c3947?a=0xd8e05701eff33acfda0a8e24c04070347703c72c)

I'm doing the following (the code is in Ruby, but should be self-explanatory):

```
require 'ethereum'

value = 14

account_a_address = "0xd8e05701eFf33acfDA0A8e24C04070347703c72C"
account_b_address = "0x3A70Ceac36c8111a95b573d76aD75B7ba898662b"
contract_address = "0x1caf5380b7adc2e4e93c2828f895693ff38c3947"

Ethereum::Singleton.setup do |c|
  c.default_account = account_a_address
end

Ethereum::Contract.create(
  file: "/Users/gmile/projects/ico-scripts/contracts/02-14-2018-1518620826/contract_text.sol",
  address: contract_address
)

contract = EugeneToken.new
tx = contract.transact.transfer(account_b_address, value * 1_000_000_00)

puts tx.id
```

For some reason the transaction is qualified as **`Contract Creation`**. Why?

[image]

I double-checked with the documentation for [`ethereum.rb`](https://github.com/EthWorks/ethereum.rb) Ruby gem. The readme states that I can use the contract from blockchain by specifying an address of the contract deployed, as well a path to `.sol` file as parameters to `Ethereum::Contract.create()` call.

Comment: Seems to be like contract creation is failed

Comment: @Jitendra Kumar. Balla but I don't intend to create a new contract. I'm trying to use existing contract, deployed on the network, as a basis for my transaction. Looks like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Your contract is invalid. Valid contract has contract code. Your contract doesn't have bytecode. So EVM will treat as a invalid contract. Check your rb file.

Comment: But it is valid, isn't it? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x1caf5380b7adc2e4e93c2828f895693ff38c3947 Or do you mean the contract logic is somehow malformed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.

The problem was that I had multiple contracts in the `.sol` file, where the actual *main* contract was being assembled (inherited?) from several smaller ones. This [`tutorial1_contract.sol`](https://github.com/bitfwdcommunity/Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial%201/tutorial1_contract.sol) file served as a template from which I made my own contract.

To fix this, I specified the `contract_index` to the `Ethereum::Contract.create()` call:

```
Ethereum::Contract.create(
  file: "/Users/gmile/projects/ico-scripts/contracts/02-14-2018-1518620826/contract_text.sol",
  address: contract_address,
  contract_index: 2
)
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer :-) (There might be an imposed delay of 48 hours, in which case, come back then and do so... )

Comment: @RichardHorrocks will do