# Transfer ERC20 tokens by ruby

Tags: tokens, erc-20, abi, ruby

I found only one semi-automatic [solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39773/cannot-transfer-erc20-token-bad-instruction-error?rq=1) to transfer tokens from one wallet to another.

But i want to do that by [web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api) way on ruby stack. Could you guys explain me, how exatly to get data for eth_sendTransaction `data` field with no using web3js (`contract.transfer.getData("0xCb...", 10, {from: "0x26..."})`).

**UPD.**

I got the point about components of data.

For example let's get transaction [0xd21fa94958692c0aa3523ae9e8984067976483ec57642554a1dda0417e3337e2](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd21fa94958692c0aa3523ae9e8984067976483ec57642554a1dda0417e3337e2)

Input data:

> MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
>   [0]:  000000000000000000000000c1816acca0a3a120fc980c58cb485d41f2b30e8e
>   [1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39773/cannot-transfer-erc20-token-bad-instruction-error?rq=1):  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007530

1. So, MethodID is encrypted function by `keccak256`. By than i am trying to get this result by same logic:

> Digest::SHA3.new(256).digest('transfer(address,uint256)') 
>   => "\xA9\x05\x9C\xBB*\xB0\x9E\xB2\x19X?JY\xA5\xD0b:\xDE4m\x96+\xCDNF\xB1\x1D\xA0G\xC9\x04\x9B"

Why do I get different resultsЮ

2. Second parameter is address (`000000000000000000000000c1816AcCA0a3A120fc980c58CB485D41F2B30E8e`). Original one is `0xc1816AcCA0a3A120fc980c58CB485D41F2B30E8e`. Next we trim few hex chars and what we should do next to generate same result?
3. And last param is amount. What should we do to convert 3 tokens to `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007530`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four bytes of the `data` field should be the *function selector*. The function selector is the first four bytes of the keccak-256 hash of the canonical function signature. In this case, `keccak256("transfer(address,uint256)")` (`0xa9059cbb`).

The next 32 bytes should be the address (left-padded) you're transferring to, and the 32 bytes after that should be the amount.

**EDIT**

Based on further questions in the edited question.

1. It looks like you're using SHA3 instead of keccak-256.
2. I'm not sure what your question here is.
3. 0x7530 == 30000. If that's "3" tokens, then the token is using four decimal places. (3 * 10^4 == 30000 == 0x7530.)

Comment: Thanks for answer buddy. And I'm sorry, because for me it's still part of magic box. Updated the question.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: 1. It should be same https://github.com/phusion/digest-sha3-ruby. But in any case i can handle this. 2-3. I forgot about decimals, not all is clear. I really appreciate your help.